# Error updating R with updateR: argument is of length zero

Tags: r

I have the following problem...

> library(updateR) 
> A new version R of 4.0.3 is available for update! 
> run updateR() to get the latest R on your macOS! \

> updateR() 
> Enter password for xxxx: xxxx 
> Updated ~/.Rprofile 
> Password:Error in if (!compactible) stop(sprintf(e, status$latest, macOS), call. = FALSE) :
> argument is of length zero

Do you have any idea how to solve it??

Just in case, the password is correct.

Comment: Where is the `updateR` package from? There exists `installr::updateR`, but it makes no reference to `compactible` in its [source](https://github.com/talgalili/installr/search?q=compactible).

Comment: I am not sure, I followed the procedure described here: https://github.com/AndreaCirilloAC/updateR, and then library(updateR) --> update()

Comment: That page starts with *"previously installed package retrieval feautre is currently available only if launching udpater from base R rather than IDE like Rstudio. previously installed package retrieval feature is in beta mode and you may need to manually install back your packages after upgrading R version"*. That to me suggests that it is also the case for R-update, not just package-update. (I don't know.) If you can reproduce this outside of the RStudio IDE, then I suggest you file a [bug report](https://github.com/AndreaCirilloAC/updateR/issues/new).

Comment: I tried using just the base R to install and run the package, no luck, same error...

Comment: Just a little bit more research for you: https://github.com/AndreaCirilloAC/updateR/issues/37.

Comment: Thank you! it is good to know that I am not alone! :)

Comment: Just added a comment to https://github.com/AndreaCirilloAC/updateR/issues/37 : tried solution offered by @BenoitFayolle , but it too fails